# NSManagedObject "on update" method?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I want to set update date to `NSManagedObject` each time object is changed.
Is there method similar to `awakeFromInsert` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`.

This notification is (source Apple doc)

> Posted when values of properties of objects contained in a managed
>   object context are changed.

A typical example for using it it is well explained in Marcus Zarra's [PARENT WATCHING ITS CHILD](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/10/14/parent-watching-its-child/) blog post.

Hope that helps.